# Ayuda para recorrer niveles de un JSON con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Quisiera saber como puedo hacer para recorrer con JavaScript este Array hasta llegar al nivel que dice item resaltado con amarillo

```
{
"SOAP-ENV:Envelope": {
    "$": {
        "SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/",
        "xmlns:SOAP-ENV": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
        "xmlns:xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
        "xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
        "xmlns:SOAP-ENC": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    },
    "SOAP-ENV:Body": {
        "ns1:creditosVencidosResponse": {
            "$": {
                "xmlns:ns1": "http://192.168.0.194/testMobilSoft/servicio.php?wsdl"
            },
            "datos": {
                "$": {
                    "xsi:type": "SOAP-ENC:Array",
                    "SOAP-ENC:arrayType": ":[1]"
                },
                "item": {
                    "$": {
                        "xsi:type": "xsd:"
                    },
                    "item": [
                        {
                            "cod_credito": {
                                "_": "2025",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "identificacion_cliente": {
                                "_": "234234",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "no_pagare": {
                                "_": "3361",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "tipo_credito": {
                                "_": "0",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "oficina": {
                                "_": "1",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "estado_libranza": {
                                "_": "DESEMBOLSO",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "fecha_aprobacion": {
                                "_": "2014-01-20",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "monto_credito": {
                                "_": "4015776",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "valor_descuento": {
                                "_": "593852",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "valor_desembolso": {
                                "_": "3323324",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "fecha_desembolso": {
                                "_": "2014-01-20",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "cuotas": {
                                "_": "60",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "valor_cuota": {
                                "_": "110000",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "fecha_inicio_descuento": {
                                "_": "2014-01-30",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "fecha_ultimo_pago": {
                                "_": "2018-03-30",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "fecha_proximo_pago": {
                                "_": "2018-04-30",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "dias_mora": {
                                "_": "24",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "saldo_capital": {
                                "_": "998506",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "pagaduria": {
                                "_": "2",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "prop_cartera": {
                                "_": "1",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "nombre": {
                                "_": "NOMBRE DEL TERCERO",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "centro_costo": {
                                "_": "1",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "tipo_documento": {
                                "_": "1",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "apellido1": {
                                "_": "APELLIDO",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "apellido2": {
                                "_": "APELLIDO 2",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "nombre1": {
                                "_": "NOMBRE 1",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "nombre2": {
                                "_": "NOMBRE 2",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "lugar_nacimiento": {
                                "_": "BARRANQUILLA - ATLANTICO",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "estado_civil": {
                                "_": "C",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "sexo": {
                                "_": "FEMENINO",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "tipo_vivienda": {
                                "_": "FAMILIAR",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "tiempo_vivienda": {
                                "_": "12",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "nivel_educativo": {
                                "_": "6",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "ocupacion": {
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:nil": "true"
                                }
                            },
                            "direccion": {
                                "_": "KRA ",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "telefono": {
                                "_": "123123",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "celular": {
                                "_": "12312312",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "correo": {
                                "_": "no tiene",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "ciudad": {
                                "_": "8001",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "fecha_nacimiento": {
                                "_": "1955-05-08",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "direccion_correspondencia": {
                                "_": "KRA",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            },
                            "lugar_correspondencia": {
                                "_": "8001",
                                "$": {
                                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Y lo que trato de hacer es que quede de esta forma porque era un XML que estoy transformado a un JSON

```
{
"datos":{
    "cod_credito":2025,
    "identificacion_cliente":12345,
    "no_pagare":4321,
    "...":"..."
}}
```

Comment: Escribe todo el `JSON` y te ayudamos. Mucho mejor que una captura de pantalla

Comment: Haz un `console.log` del JSON y ponlo en la pregunta, de ese modo se te podrá indicar con claridad cómo hacerlo. Para ello puedes [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/167170/edit).

Comment: Esta fue mi solucion para entrar a los otros niveles del array
 `data['SOAP-ENV:Envelope']['SOAP-ENV:Body']['ns1:creditosVencidosResponse']['datos']['item']['item'];` @Victor Herasme Perez y @A. Cedano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta fue mi solución para recorrer el **Array** de datos proveniente del **XML** que había transformado **JSON**, solo fue llegar al nivel de los datos por el nombre de cabecera del Array y luego de eso utilizar **push** para agregar los datos un objeto nuevo

```js
let datosJSON = [];

let xml = data['SOAP-ENV:Envelope']['SOAP-ENV:Body']['ns1:creditosVencidosResponse']['datos']['item']['item'];
            for (let i = 0; i < xml.length; i++) {
                datosJSON.push({
                    'id_credito': xml[i]['cod_credito']['_'],
                    'identificacion': xml[i]['identificacion_cliente']['_'],
                    'no_pagare': xml[i]['no_pagare']['_'],
                    'id_tipo_credito': xml[i]['tipo_credito']['_'],
                    'id_oficina': xml[i]['oficina']['_'],
                    'estado_libranza': xml[i]['estado_libranza']['_'],
                    'fecha_aprobacion': xml[i]['fecha_aprobacion']['_'],
                    'monto_credito': xml[i]['monto_credito']['_'],
                    'valor_descuento': xml[i]['valor_descuento']['_'],
                    'valor_desembolso': xml[i]['valor_desembolso']['_'],
                    'fecha_desembolso': xml[i]['fecha_desembolso']['_'],
                    'cuotas': xml[i]['cuotas']['_'],
                    'valor_cuota': xml[i]['valor_cuota']['_'],
                    'fecha_inicio_descuento': xml[i]['fecha_inicio_descuento']['_'],
                    'fecha_ultimo_pago': xml[i]['fecha_ultimo_pago']['_'],
                    'fecha_proximo_pago': xml[i]['fecha_proximo_pago']['_'],
                    'dias_mora': xml[i]['dias_mora']['_'],
                    'saldo_capital': xml[i]['saldo_capital']['_'],
                    'id_pagaduria': xml[i]['pagaduria']['_'],
                    'id_propietariocartera': xml[i]['prop_cartera']['_'],
                    'nombre': xml[i]['nombre']['_'],
                    'id_centro_costo': xml[i]['centro_costo']['_'],
                    'id_tipo_documento': xml[i]['tipo_documento']['_'],
                    'apellido1': xml[i]['apellido1']['_'],
                    'apellido2': xml[i]['apellido2']['_'],
                    'nombre1': xml[i]['nombre1']['_'],
                    'nombre2': xml[i]['nombre2']['_'],
                    'lugar_nacimiento': xml[i]['lugar_nacimiento']['_'],
                    'estado_civil': xml[i]['estado_civil']['_'],
                    'sexo': xml[i]['sexo']['_'],
                    'tipo_vivienda': xml[i]['tipo_vivienda']['_'],
                    'tiempo_vivienda': xml[i]['tiempo_vivienda']['_'],
                    'id_nivel_educativo': xml[i]['nivel_educativo']['_'],
                    'ocupacion': xml[i]['ocupacion']['_'],
                    'direccion': xml[i]['direccion']['_'],
                    'telefono': xml[i]['telefono']['_'],
                    'celular': xml[i]['celular']['_'],
                    'correo': xml[i]['correo']['_'],
                    'codigo_ciudad': xml[i]['ciudad']['_'],
                    'fecha_nacimiento': xml[i]['fecha_nacimiento']['_'],
                    'direccion_correspondencia': xml[i]['direccion_correspondencia']['_'],
                    'lugar_correspondencia': xml[i]['lugar_correspondencia']['_']
                });
```

Datos de salida del Arreglo

```
{
"id_credito": "2025",
"identificacion": "3123",
"no_pagare": "8967",
"id_tipo_credito": "0",
"id_oficina": "1",
"estado_libranza": "DESEMBOLSO",
"fecha_aprobacion": "2014-01-20",
"monto_credito": "4015776",
"valor_descuento": "593852",
"valor_desembolso": "3323324",
"fecha_desembolso": "2014-01-20",
"cuotas": "60",
"valor_cuota": "110000",
"fecha_inicio_descuento": "2014-01-30",
"fecha_ultimo_pago": "2018-03-30",
"fecha_proximo_pago": "2018-04-30",
"dias_mora": "25",
"saldo_capital": "998506",
"id_pagaduria": "2",
"id_propietariocartera": "1",
"nombre": "...",
"id_centro_costo": "1",
"id_tipo_documento": "1",
"apellido1": "...",
"apellido2": "...",
"nombre1": "...",
"nombre2": "...",
"lugar_nacimiento": "...",
"estado_civil": "C",
"sexo": "FEMENINO",
"tipo_vivienda": "FAMILIAR",
"tiempo_vivienda": "12",
"id_nivel_educativo": "6",
"direccion": "KRA ",
"telefono": "1234",
"celular": "1234",
"correo": "no tiene",
"codigo_ciudad": "8001",
"fecha_nacimiento": "1955-05-08",
"direccion_correspondencia": "KRA",
"lugar_correspondencia": "8001"
```

}